# Wubi: Permission denied: 'C:\\boot.ini'

Tags: wubi

I got a problem with installing ubuntu with the help of wubi.
My configuration is a laptop with single hdd, Windows XP SP3 and my user account with admin rights. Wubi version is rev245.

I can manually change the file boot.ini (and I already removed the read-only flag) but wubi always crashes with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 606, in modify_bootini
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 239, in write_file
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\boot.ini'
```

I added the following line manually

```
c:\wubildr.mbr="Ubuntu"
```

but I am stuck with a grub shell bootloader that doesn't recognize any kernels (as these files weren't copied).

Is there a switch to tell wubi to proceed even if it can't access boot.ini perhaps?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 2):

Try to login to the account with administrator permissions instead of just selecting Run as
.. Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure wubi.exe is run as Administrator. I think you can right-click, select Run as.. Administrator.

Comment: I already tried this, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't really understand how this is not an answer. It was not a request for feedback. It was an answer based on the assumption that if he's not allowed to open a system file, it's because he's not running the program as an administrator -- which is required.

Answer (score -1):

Right click>run as>USERNAME>Untick the box underneath  worked for me

Comment: I might want to detail this answer a bit more. For starters, "right click" on what?